# Use Webpack to compile .sass - which way is faster?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass, sass-loader

We have a single index.scss file that @import all other scss files in our project. Currently, we use `node-sass-chokidar`(Libsass core) to compile index.scss to index.css every time we build the project.

I wonder would the process be faster or slower if I use `sass-loader` to import index.scss directly? A package named `fast-sass-loader` also gets my attention.

I know that scss files need to be compiled anyway but I am not sure which compiler would be more efficient as the project grows larger...As a junior, I am having a hard time make the comparison. Could anyone share some ideas how should I evaluate them?

Comment: You could try both approaches and see what is faster for your use case. I think whatever difference there will be, it will be negligible.

Comment: We initialized the project for just a month so the size of all scss file is still very small...Yes, the difference would be negligible for now.

Comment: I think transpiling stylesheets is unlikely to ever take much time, even as your project grows. As your code base increases there are tons of other things that would take priority if you were looking at optimizing build time. If you wanted, you could steal a large set of SASS files from some public project and then do some speed testing of various tools for transpiling it. Though again, there's almost certainly better ways to spend your time.

Comment: I heard css compiling could take ~1 minutes and then got nervous. You're right...I am easily caught by what in front of me and eager for a silver bullet. It seems testing is again the best way to find out which method should I follow.

Comment: Webpack sass-loader also uses `node-sass` to compile the Sass, I'm not sure where any discrepancies in time could come from. The compiler is the same, ultimately. The choice lies more within workflow and architecture than performance.

Comment: @EdmundReed Yeah, thank you for your reminder. I found this discussion which clarifies things a bit. It seems that other Webpack processes affect the total time. 
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/296